# Is __atomic_compare_exchange equivalent to _InterlockedCompareExchange?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

The Visual C++ compiler has an intrinsic called [_InterlockedCompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttk2z1ws(v=vs.140).aspx), and while looking for a non-Microsoft-specific alternative, I found GCC's [__atomic_compare_exchange](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) (formerly known as [__sync_val_compare_and_swap](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html)) built-in function. As far as I understand, both of these implement an atomic compare-exchange operation.

Am I correct in my understanding that these two functions are practically equivalent (apart from the order in which they expect their parameters)?

Also, on *x86* and *x86_64*, are these both compiled to `CMPXCHG`?

Comment: Not quite.  Use the fish, the compilers you use have an option to generate an assembly listing.  It is /FA for MSVC++, it is -S for GCC.  Now you'll never have to ask a question like this again.

Comment: @HansPassant From reading the documentation, I think they are equivalent. Obviously, I would not have asked this question if I was completely sure. Please write an answer if you know better.